# Foreign Key (don't want to edit it) error

Tags: symfony, hyperlink, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have a little problem i don't know why i can't edit my foreign key ($idProfile) but i can edit an other value from the database :

I can change the value enable for exemple but not the idProfile when i try to change it i have this error : "An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates." don't know if that can help thx for help guys :p

my Profile controller :

```
 /**
 * Creates a new profile entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{id}", name="profile_new")
 */
public function newProfileAction(Request $request, User $user)
{

    $loggedAs = $this->getUser();
    $username =  $loggedAs->getUsername();

    $profile = new Profile();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProfileType::class, $profile);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $profile->setLastConnexion(new \DateTime('now'));
        $profile->setCreatedAccount(new \DateTime('now'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

        $user->setEnabled('1');
        $user->setIdLocation($profile->getId());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();



        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/user/new_profile.html.twig', array(
        'profile' => $profile,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'username' => $username,
    ));
}
```

My userEntity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints=
{@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_id_uindex", columns={"id"}), 
@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_username_uindex", columns=
{"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_profile_id_fk", 
columns={"id_profile"}), @ORM\Index(name="user_localisation_id_fk", 
columns={"id_location"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("username", groups={"Default", "Patch"})
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';
const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=32)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
 *     message="Password must be seven characters long and contain at least one digit code, upper case, and lower case letter!",
 *     groups={"Default", "Patch"}
 * )
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
protected $enabled = '1';

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Localisation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Localisation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_location", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $idLocation;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Profile
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_profile", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $idProfile;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="idUserOne")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friend",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_one", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_two", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idUserTwo;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserInvited")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="list_invited",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idPlaceInvited;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", mappedBy="idUserPresent")
 */
protected $idPlacePresent;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserPlace")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_place",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
protected $idPlacePlace;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", length=200)
 * @Serializer\Exclude()
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->idUserTwo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlaceInvited = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePresent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePlace = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId(int $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @param string $username
 */
public function setUsername(string $username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword(string $password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->enabled;
}

/**
 * @param bool $enabled
 */
public function setEnabled(bool $enabled)
{
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdLocation()
{
    return $this->idLocation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idLocation
 */
public function setIdLocation($idLocation)
{
    $this->idLocation = $idLocation;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdProfile()
{
    return $this->idProfile;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idProfile
 */
public function setIdProfile($idProfile)
{
    $this->idProfile = $idProfile;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdUserTwo()
{
    return $this->idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo
 */
public function setIdUserTwo(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo)
{
    $this->idUserTwo = $idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlaceInvited()
{
    return $this->idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited
 */
public function setIdPlaceInvited(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited)
{
    $this->idPlaceInvited = $idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePresent()
{
    return $this->idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent
 */
public function setIdPlacePresent(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent)
{
    $this->idPlacePresent = $idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePlace()
{
    return $this->idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace
 */
public function setIdPlacePlace(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace)
{
    $this->idPlacePlace = $idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

/**
 * @param array $roles
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

/**
 * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
 *
 * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
 *
 * @return string|null The salt
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
 * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}
```

}

some screen of data base : [https://ibb.co/iCSnWy
p
[https://ibb.co/cZZedd
p

Comment: doctrine doesn't allow direct editing of the foreign keys through entities; you need to change the referenced entity or update the relation - or if you really want to do it, create a Dao with raw sql

Comment: could I have more precision on the fact to create a dao with raw sql ? (i just want to set to my idprofile the id of profile) or even to update the relation , it's my first time doing this so i try my best :p

Comment: @zedling need help, do you have an exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'll have to do it this way:

```
$loggedAs = $this->getUser(); // get the user

$profile = new Profile();
// set up profile variables 
// [...]

$profile->setUser($loggedAs);    // case 1
// or, depending on your implementation
$loggedAs->addProfile($profile); // case 2

// persist, flush etc
```

With doctrine the foreign key handling is behind the scenes, 
you don't have to worry about them if your mappings are correct

So instead of fkeys, you just attach entities.
Depending on your implementation (the relation can be uni- or bi-directional) you only have to chose one of the 2 cases.

I hope it helps, more [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/associations.html).